# How to convert Tensorflow-lite's output from interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index']) into score, x, y coordinates?

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I am implementing Tensorflow-lite for pose detection using webcam's live feed.

I am familiar with Posenet implementation using javascript from https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet

I was expecting when i call 
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])

I would get the same size array as what the posenet javascript version is giving back. What I get is an array of (1,23,17,17) size.

How do I go about converting that output array into one similar to what is found in that posenet website?

I tried to use the code snippet from this person's Java implementation but it does not seem to be working correctly:
[How to use outputs of posenet model in tflite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136861/how-to-use-outputs-of-posenet-model-in-tflite/55288616#55288616)